# Pythonic way to iterate over lists inside a dict in parallel AS a dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I realize that the title of this question might not be immediately super clear, so on an example:
My dict contains lists as follows (assume there's nothing else in it):

```py
packed = {
    'names': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    'values': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
}
```

What I want to do is to iterate over each of these lists (as many as there might be) in parallel, but so that **during each iteration I have a dict with a single element of each list**. I imagine something like this:

```py
for pack in smartIterate(packed): #how to "smartIterate"?
    print(pack['names'], pack['values'])
    #pack is equal to {'names':'a', 'values':'A'} in the first iteration
```

printing out that:

```
a, A
b, B
c, C
d, D
```

I realize this can be done with explicitly iterating over the length of one sublist and constructing a dict during each iteration:

```py
for i in range(len(packed.values()[0])):
    pack = dict(zip(packed.keys(),[v[i] for v in packed.values()]))
```

but it feels like there is a cleaner, more efficient - *pythonic* - way to do that.

Similar questions:

- [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21911483) didn't clearly involve iterating over lists contained within a dict - mine is specifically about it,
- [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986188) didn't involve parallel lists within a dict,
- [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287) didn't involve dicts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pythonic iteration over multiple lists in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21911483/pythonic-iteration-over-multiple-lists-in-parallel)

Comment: Not a duplicate, as the crucial part of this problem is to have those parallel values in a dict whose keys distinguish which list did the values come from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly use `zip` with `dict.values`

**Ex:**

```
packed = {
    'names': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    'values': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
}

keysValue = packed.keys()
for pack in zip(*packed.values()): 
    print( dict(zip(keysValue, pack)) )
```

**Output:**

```
{'values': 'A', 'names': 'a'}
{'values': 'B', 'names': 'b'}
{'values': 'C', 'names': 'c'}
{'values': 'D', 'names': 'd'}
```

*Or in a one line using list comprehension*

```
keysValue = packed.keys()
print( [dict(zip(keysValue, pack)) for pack in zip(*packed.values())] )
#[{'values': 'A', 'names': 'a'}, {'values': 'B', 'names': 'b'}, {'values': 'C', 'names': 'c'}, {'values': 'D', 'names': 'd'}]
```

Comment: I am aware of that, but this doesn't give me an intermediate dict. `pack` is supposed to be `{'names': 'a', 'values': 'A'}` during every iteration (example given for the first iter). I will highlight the relevant sentence in my question to make this more clear.

Comment: Updated snippet is that what you want?

Comment: Yes! The list comprehension one-liner is particularly pretty. Thanks :)